# Extracting a value from a checkbox - C#, WPF

Tags: c#, checkbox

I'm new to c# and the visual studio, done a bit in visual basic before.  Any help much appreciated.

I'm trying to get a form to change a variable depending on if a checkbox is checked or not.
So the user clicks a button and the variable has a value, but if the checkbox is checked it has another.

So I'm trying to have

```
        if (Othersite.Checked)
            site = "Site B";
        else
            site = "Site A";
```

If I put it as this, the message at the bottom says "Togglebutton.checked must be on the left of += or -="

However, if I put

if (Othersite.Checked += true)
site = "Site B";
else
site = "Site A";

The error is "CS0029    Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'"

Where am i going wrong?

I've tried looking around on here, but can't see anything too similar.  Or the results haven't worked in the visual studio.

Comment: If you use WPF application, then `CheckBox` state stored in property `IsChecked`. `Checked` (without Is) in WPF CheckBox is event, that fires when CheckBox is checked. And subscribing to event uses `+=` operator - that what error means

Comment: Thanks for your response.
If i use ischecked, I get the following...
CS1061 'CheckBox' does not contain a definition for 'isChecked' and no accessible extension method 'isChecked' accepting a first argument of type 'CheckBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

any ideas?  thanks

Comment: `IsChecked`, not `isChecked`. Case is important

Answer (score 0):

Transferring from comments, in WPF application to get `CheckBox` state you should use `IsChecked` property:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    if (Othersite.IsChecked)
        site = "Site B";
    else
        site = "Site A";

    // or use ternary assignment:
    // site = $"Site {(Othersite.IsChecked ? "B" : "A")}";
}
```

I assume that the culprit in such misunderstanding is Windows Forms, where `CheckBox` state stored in `Checked` property (without "Is" prefix). That may confuse if you migrated(-ing) from Windows Forms to WPF.

`Checked` in WPF CheckBox became an `event`, which fires when you checking CheckBox.

You can see it in Visual Studio when putting a dot "." after your CheckBox name:
[image: WPF]

When in Windows Forms it looks:
[image: Windows Forms]

Comment: Thank you for your responses.
CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

I assume I'm missing something basic here...

When I use the ((bool)(Othersite.IsChecked = true)) to convert from a bool?  to a bool explicitly, it then just checks the box when the button is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: I've managed to get it working now

Changed your 
site = $"Site {(Othersite.IsChecked ? "B" : "A")}";

to

site = $"Site {(bool)(Othersite.IsChecked ? "B" : "A")}";

Not sure why that is?  But Thank you for your help

Comment: That's because of nullable annotations. Yes, you can explicitly cast to `bool` as you've done. Also you can use `is` keyword to cast and check: `Othersite.IsChecked is true...`